# Is the following integration "trick" valid to reduce my integrand to a constant?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_2^4 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\ln(3+x)}{\ln(9-x)}} +1}dx = 1$$

I noticed when $x$ went from $2$ to $4$, $3+x$ went from $5$ to $7$, and $9-x$ went from $7$ to $5$.

I noticed that if we reverse the interval of $9-x$ we obtain $-(9-x)$ and whose interval goes from $5$ to $7$. In short, I concluded that reversing the interval of $9-x$ yielded the expression $3+x$.

Therefore I allowed the above integral to be $$\int_2^4 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\ln(3+x)}{\ln(9-x)}} +1} dx = \int_2^4 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\ln(3+x)}{\ln(3+x)}} +1} dx.$$

Effectively, the logs cancelled and I was left with $\int_2^4 {1\over 1+1}dx =1$.

Comment: Not at all because $3+x$ and $9-x$ traverse the interval in opposite directions, $5$ to $7$ and $7$ to $5$.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? -.-

Comment: Even though the "trick" is not allowed, it is an excellent observation and good food for thought for any oncoming mathematician!

Comment: 3+x will take on the same values as 9-x but they obviously will not take on the same values at the same values of x.  Obviously 3+x is not the same as 9-x so obviously you can't exchange them.  Otherwise you can replace anything with anything.  $x^2 + 27x + 3 = 3$ when $x = 0$ and $31$ when $x=1$. And  $(1-x)(e^{x\ln 31}) + 3x = 3$ when $x =1$ and $31$ when $x=0$ but obviously we can't swap them.

Comment: Assuming you have a spreadsheet on you computer, it should be easy to do a numerical sanity check.   Yeah, I know, that is not exactly the spirit of pure math, but sometimes such means can prevent you from exposing your embarrassing shortcomings.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Of course not, at least not in general: the argument is wrong, even though the function is set up very cleverly.

$3+x$ and $9-x$ may cover the same interval, but for each $x$, these two expressions are different. They only coincide once, otherwise you get a fraction with different top and bottom side. Even more... even if you wanted to use symmetry to argue left and right half of the integral cancels somehow, $\ln x$ is not a linear function - its shape on the bottom and upper part of the interval is completely different. If you want to prove or disprove symmetry in this particular case, the secret will lie more deeply in the properties of the given function, not just in the reversal of the interval.

You could try to use this kind of thinking to find a substitution which makes the integration domain and the terms under the square root symmetric.

In particular: if we try $u=x-3$, we get

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\ln (6+u)}{\ln (6-u)}}+1}du$$
which looks a bit better. The *real* question is, if we exchange $u\iff -u$, does the integrand resemble the original one?

Hypothesis:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\ln (6+u)}{\ln (6-u)}}+1}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\ln (6-u)}{\ln (6+u)}}+1}$$

if $-6<u<6$. Can you proceed on your own?

Comment: Please stop here, I can take it from here now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Aside: you could just consider $y =  6-x$ rather than doing it in two steps.

Comment: You could. Also, even better is to simply recognize the form $f(q)=1/(q+1)$ which is famous for $f(1/q)=1-f(q)=q f(q)$.

Answer (score 22):

**Counterexample**:

$$\int_2^4\frac{3+x}{9-x}dx=\int_2^4\left(1-\frac{6}{9-x}\right)dx=\left.\left(x+6\log(9-x)\right)\right|_2^4=2+6\log\frac37\ne\int_2^4dx.$$

Comment: Always like counter examples...

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{2}^{4}{1 \over \root{\ln\pars{3 + x}/\ln\pars{9 - x}} + 1 }\,\dd x =
\int_{2}^{4}{\root{\ln\pars{9 - x}} \over \root{\ln\pars{3 + x}} +
\root{\ln\pars{9 - x}}}\,\dd x
\\[1cm] = &\ 
{1 \over 2}\left\{\int_{2}^{4}{\root{\ln\pars{9 - x}} \over \root{\ln\pars{3 + x}} +
\root{\ln\pars{9 - x}}}\,\dd x\right.
\\[5mm] &\
\left. + \int_{2}^{4}{\root{\ln\pars{9 - \bracks{4 + 2 - x}}} \over
\root{\ln\pars{3 + \bracks{4 + 2 - x}}} +
\root{\ln\pars{9 - \bracks{4 + 2 - x}}}}\,\dd x\right\} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{2}^{4}\dd x =
\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{1}}
\end{align}

Comment: You make the change of variable $y=2+4-x$. Usual trick for definite integrals. Good to remember.

Comment: @FDP. Yes: It's an identity. $\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{f}\left(\,x\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}x =
\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{f}\left(\,a + b - x\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: From where did the $1\over 2$ factor come from?

Comment: $$
\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{f}\left(\,x\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = 
\color{#f00}{1 \over 2}
\left[\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{f}\left(\,x\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}x +
\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{f}\left(\,x\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]
$$
Replace $\underline{one}$ of the RHS integrals by using the identity in my previous comment.